# Pod AntiAffinity doesn't work within my Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, minikube

everyone! Does anyone know where I do a mistake? I want to simulate a DaemonSet behaviour using **Deployment** and **AntiNodeAffinity** to place each pods on different nodes. If I'm using `topologyKey` set to a label [`kubernetes.io/hostname`](http://kubernetes.io/hostname) that exists on each node, it works fine. I have `1 master` and `1 worker`, using 3 replicas the last one will be in a pending state.

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-anti-affinity-5dbbbb9b9d-7jxhq   1/1     Running   0          5m38s
nginx-anti-affinity-5dbbbb9b9d-jgjs9   1/1     Running   0          5m38s
nginx-anti-affinity-5dbbbb9b9d-xv6cx   0/1     Pending   0          5m38s
```

However, if I want to place pods only on the worker nodes, I assigned a new label `type=worker` only on my worker node. So, it should run only 1 replica now and makes 2 pods in a pending state. Finally, It doesn't work and runs all pods on my nodes.  When I change `topologyKey` to any other predefined labels like `kubernetes.io/os`, that stop working properly as well...

```
k get nodes --show-labels | grep type 
                                                                                          
minikube-m02   Ready    <none>          24m   v1.24.3   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=arm64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=arm64,kubernetes.io/hostname=minikube-m02,kubernetes.io/os=linux,type=worker
```

```
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-anti-affinity-8595847fd8-4zlv4   1/1     Running   0          68s   172.17.0.4   minikube       <none>           <none>
nginx-anti-affinity-8595847fd8-95nrb   1/1     Running   0          68s   172.17.0.3   minikube       <none>           <none>
nginx-anti-affinity-8595847fd8-q598k   1/1     Running   0          68s   172.17.0.2   minikube-m02
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    id: nginx-anti-affinity
  name: nginx-anti-affinity
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      id: nginx-anti-affinity
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        id: nginx-anti-affinity
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: id
                operator: In
                values:
                - nginx-anti-affinity
            topologyKey: "type"
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

I'm trying to simulate a DaemonSet behaviour using **Deployment** and **AntiNodeAffinity** to place each pods on different nodes.

Comment: Your expectation is not clear. Please add what you wish to have in case, you have 3 replicas and only 1 worker node, what do you expect to have? Based on that the solution could be based, as you have only laid out examples and not what you want.

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav, in case of 3 replicas, 1 master node and 1 worker, I expect getting 2 running pods (like DaemonSet) and 1 pod in a pending state until a new worker node will be launched.

Comment: Are you not getting that behaviour using `topologyKey` set to a label `kubernetes.io/hostname` ?

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav, I was interested in my custom labels. I found the appropriate answer in the k8s documentation. All nodes should have been labeled, otherwise, it works in an unexpected way. **Note:** Pod anti-affinity requires nodes to be consistently labelled, in other words, every node in the cluster must have an appropriate label matching `topologyKey`. If some or all nodes are missing the specified `topologyKey` label, it can lead to unintended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found the appropriate answer in the [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#types-of-inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity). All nodes should have been labeled, otherwise, it works in an unexpected way.

**Note:** Pod anti-affinity requires nodes to be consistently labelled, in other words, every node in the cluster must have an appropriate label matching `topologyKey`. If some or all nodes are missing the specified `topologyKey` label, it can lead to unintended behavior.